# Американский сервис приёма разной валюты

Tags: платежи

Вот есть робокасса, есть интеркасса. А есть ли такой же американский? Т.е. там чтобы была возможность приёма различных валют PayPal, VISA ну и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Amazon FPS](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)
2. Собственно, Paypal - принимать PP и кредитки;

С любопытством почитаю другие ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли)))